# Combining Classifiers with Keras

Tags: keras

I Have the prediction of three models: CNN, LSTM, DNN.

```
model1_pred = nn_model1.predict(x_val)
model2_pred  = nn_model2.predict(x_val)
model3_pred  = nn_model3.predict(x_val)
```

I would like to combine those models with Keras but I not have any idea. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the functional api to stack your networks. This lets you call neural nets as if they were layers.

```python
from keras.models import Model
x_val = Input(shape=(<shape of your input>))
model1_pred = nn_model1(x_val)
model2_pred = nn_model2(x_val)
model3_pred = nn_model3(x_val)
combined_model = Model([model1_pred, model2_pred, model3_pred], [<outputs>])
```